# Version not updated in bean after persist

Tags: jpa

I have a JPA entity Person which has a @Version long version field. I do the following:

```
<<transaction - begin>>
person.getId() --> == NULL
person.setVersion(1);
em.persist(person);
person.getId() --> returns 1 (this one is generated inside the persist call)
person.getVersion(); --> returns 1
<<transaction - end>>
```

Now if I check the DB, the version = 2, but the bean incorrectly contains 1.

I see the id of the person entity gets reflected correctly in the person instance. However, the version remains the one before calling persist(). Why?

Comment: Why do you expect a version updated before commit? the spec doesn't make that promise IIRC

Comment: @DataNucleus - I want to send this version to the view layer so that the next entity update will not produce an OptimisticLockingException

Comment: Tried a flush()? Just that things aren't guaranteed to go to the DB immediately, and DataNucleus JPA for one would provide the version after flush but not before. Check your JPA impl docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are "outside" the specification borders:

> An entity may access the state of its version ﬁeld or property or
>   export a method for use by the application to access the version, but
>   must not modify the version value. Only the persistence provider is
>   permitted to set or update the value of the version attribute in the
>   object.

(Quote from [JPA specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/))

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Matt! I'm setting the version just for the sake of the example, but the problem is I never get the "new value" of this field after persist is called. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: You could try `em.refresh()` after persist, but I am not sure if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Oh, you need to do `em.refresh(person)`, but I think you did it this way.

Comment: Yes. I observed a new thing: if I set the version to NULL before doing persist(...), the bean gets updated with version=0.

Comment: in fact...if I put NULL, in DB the version=1 while the bean gets a "0" value. This is very weird